# maven compile error - [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact

Tags: maven

New to Maven, possible newbie error.

I am doing the pluralsight introduction to jenkins course.  in it we clone the git repository  `http://github.com/g0t4/jenkins2-course-spring-boot` in its subdirectory `jenkins2-course-spring-boot\spring-boot-samples\spring-boot-sample-atmosphere` there is the following pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-samples</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-atmosphere</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Boot Atmosphere Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Atmosphere Sample</description>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-javascript</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

when I try to compile with mvn compile, I get the following build log with errors:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from spring-snapshots: http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to spring-snapshots (http://repo.spring.io/snapshot): Authorization failed for http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 403 Forbidden
Downloading from spring-snapshots: http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-bom-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshots (http://repo.spring.io/snapshot): Authorization failed for http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-bom-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom 403 Forbidden @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\JenkinsTryOut\jenkins2-course-spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 2058, column 16
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar is missing. @ line 46, column 15
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-sample-atmosphere:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\JenkinsTryOut\jenkins2-course-spring-boot\spring-boot-samples\spring-boot-sample-atmosphere\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshots (http://repo.spring.io/snapshot): Authorization failed for http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-bom-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom 403 Forbidden @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\JenkinsTryOut\jenkins2-course-spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 2058, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar is missing. @ line 46, column 15
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

java version is:

```
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

maven version is:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: As the error message says *Authorization failed for http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-bom-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom 403 Forbidden*

Comment: First I have my doubts that you need SNAPSHOT's cause there are releases available of Spring Boot ..furthermore you are accessing via `http` instead of `https`  and furthermore you are using a really old version of Spring Boot...current versions is 2.2.4.RELEASE ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried changing to https, and got the same result.  when I changed to 2.2.4.RELEASE, I got a new error (which is progress!) `Non-resolvable parent POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-sample-atmosphere:2.2.4.RELEASE: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-samples:pom:2.2.4.RELEASE in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10`

Comment: @Jens Hi, I saw the authorization failed, not sure what would be the cause of this.  my best guess is they changed the properties on the file, but really I am grubbing around in the dark.

Comment: @PaulSpencer I think you need an authentication to access the repository in your settings.xml. Try to open the url in your browser, maybe you get moreinformations

Comment: @PaulSpencer That means you have either a very old version of Maven which I strongly recommend to upgrade or you have configured to access central via `http` instead of `https` in your `settings.xml` because  https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https

Answer (score 14):

It appears a mixture of not reading the comments and @khmarbaise advice.

in the pom.xml it said:

```
<parent>
    <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-samples</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

so when I changed the artifactId to spring-boot-starter-parent, as the comment suggested, and updated the version to 2.2.4.RELEASE as @khmarbaise suggested I got the following parent element of the pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and then compiled with `mvn compile` I was able to successfully compile.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. After use this solution (it worked) I see it also solved in the "Discussion" tab on the course page in Pluralsight. Just saying for everyone with this problem or another related to that course.

Answer (score 5):

I also started watching the same course, and issued the same problem. 
The answer you gave is only partially true. Changing the version to `2.2.4.RELEASE` will cause you to face many errors while trying to run `mvn test` since in the later releases some of the classes are thrown out (ex. `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration`). The best solution would be to change artifactId to `spring-boot-starter-parent` as you said and version to `1.4.0.RELEASE` and you'll be able to run all your maven comands without getting errors. So, let's say, fully answer would be:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it gave me new errors toward the end, they were 

`[ERROR] Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.`

So tried the option mentioned above using `2.2.4.RELEASE` and it worked without errors.  Don't know about the `mvn test` yet.

Comment: I am also facing the exact same issue. If using `1.4.0.RELEASE` then compile is failing with above mentioned error of `Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later`. If using `2.2.4.RELEASE` then getting same error of `autoconfiguration` in `mvn test`. Can somebody tell what would be the complete solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple pom.xml files have reference to BUILD-SNAPSHOT versions of libraries which are no longer available. Following steps worked for me:-

1. Create your github account
2. Fork repository
   https://github.com/g0t4/jenkins2-course-spring-boot
3. Clone your forked repository to your local directory (say /user/ponson/jenkins2-course-spring-boot)
4. Open bash terminal and change your current directory to your local git directory (/user/ponson/jenkins2-course-spring-boot)
5. Run below command to replace occurances of '1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT' with '1.4.0.RELEASE' in pom.xml files
   find . -name pom.xml | xargs sed -i 's/1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/1.4.0.RELEASE/g'
6. Open spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml for editing and replace '4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT' with '4.3.2.RELEASE'
7. Stage your changes to local repository using command 'git add .'
8. commit your changes (git commit -m '<>')
9. Push your changes to your remote git repository (git push origin). Keep your github credentials handy and enter when prompted.

The fixes are available in below forked repository. May be you can use it directly.
https://github.com/PonsonT/jenkins2-course-spring-boot